# How to pass date as a field in jrxml of JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to pass date as a field to the jrxml.
Following is the code for it.

```xml
<xyLineChart> 
    <chart evaluationTime="Band"> 
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="500"/> 
    </chart> 
    <xyDataset> 
        <dataset incrementType="None"/> 
        <xySeries> 
            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["CpuUsageGraph"]]></seriesExpression> 
            <xValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date($F{time}.getTime())]]></xValueExpression> 
            <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{cpuUsage}]]></yValueExpression>
        </xySeries> 
    </xyDataset> 
    <linePlot> 
        <plot/> 
    </linePlot> 
</xyLineChart>
```

But it is not working.
Its giving error as can not cast from date to number.
Then how to convert it?

Comment: Code is

<xyLineChart> 
<chart evaluationTime="Band"> 
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="500"/> 
</chart> 
<xyDataset> 
<dataset incrementType="None"/> 
<xySeries> 
<seriesExpression> 
<![CDATA["CpuUsageGraph"]]> 
</seriesExpression> 
<xValueExpression> 
<![CDATA[new java.util.Date($F{time}.getTime())]]> 
</xValueExpression> 
<yValueExpression> 
<![CDATA[$F{cpuUsage}]]>
</yValueExpression>
</xySeries> 
</xyDataset> 
<linePlot> 
<plot/> 
</linePlot> 
</xyLineChart>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `time` field in the constructor of `Date`. No need for that.

Instead of this:

```
java.util.Date($F{time}.getTime())
```

use this:

```
$F{time}
```

If you want the `long` value of it: then use this

```
$F{time}.getTime()
```

**UPDATE**
I didn't notice you are using a chart, here is a new answer:

In charts, X and Y value expressions should be any `Number` object, check subclasses in [Number Class JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), in your case you are getting the `long` value of your `Time` field, which cannot be cast to `Number`, you will need to define a new object, for example:

```
new Long($F{time}.getTime())
```

**Side Note:** in this case the report will compile and work, BUT, you are getting the number of milliseconds and using it in your chart. I don't think that is what you want exactly. So i would suggest extracting a specific field from your `Date` field like *Day*. *Month*, *Year* ... etc

Comment: I tried that.
But its also not working.
Its giving error as can not cast from long to number.

Comment: Hey thanks.
Its working now.
but as you said it is taking the values in millisecond.
so how to display that milliseconds in hh mm ss format?

Comment: its not about the display, its about how you want your data to be presented. In your case, do you want to show how the CPU usage changed every 1 second? or every 1 minute? ...etc, the X expression should be set to this value. Also notice that the Label can have an expression also.

Comment: I want the hh:mm:ss format to display on x-axis.
How to convert millisecond to this format in jrxml?
Or is there any other way to display the time in hh:mm:ss format in jasper?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the attached JRXML. However, open your JRXML file in a text editor, and check that the field is defined something like this:

```
<field name="MyDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

Comment: Yes.
it is defined like
<field name="time" class="java.util.Date"/>